# What commands do I use to get the result as the image?

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis, functions, graphics3d

How can I get what comes out in the image, if possible with the limits of integration.

the solids are for example

$\textbf{x^2+y^2+z^2 =8}$  and   $\textbf{z=x^2+y^2}$

[image]

I need something like the image, if the integration limits come out better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 30}}, 12];
r2 = Cylinder[{{-20, 0, 15}, {0, 0, 15}}, 10];
r3 = Cylinder[{{20, 0, 15}, {0, 0, 15}}, 10];
r = RegionUnion[r1, r2, r3];
Region[r]
```

[image]

```
rr1 = RegionIntersection[r1, r2];
rr2 = RegionIntersection[r1, r3];
rr = RegionUnion[rr1, rr2];
Region[rr, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

You can use the regions `r` and `rr` inside the integration routine.

Comment: Hello
I use the version of Mayhematica 10.4, I do not have the commands. What version do you have?

Comment: @juanmuñoz Try using `DiscretizeRegion` instead of the `Region` function. That should be available since v. 10.

Comment: @juanmuñoz, I use V11.1. The `Region` command just draws the regions defined before.

Comment: two things
The second command served me, but when I made the second order, the video controller went down RAM?
On the other hand as it is done with these example solidsthe solids 

$\textbf{x^2+y^2+z^2 =8}$  and   $\textbf{z=x^2+y^2}$

Comment: That's true, the `DiscretizeRegion` requires a lot of memory. You can try to play with `MaxCellMeasure` option inside it to decrease the number of polygons in resulting figure. BTW, it is needed only for drawing of figure. You can use the `r` and `rr` for calculations